# Getting ajax error everytime I include the variable ntaReqRef

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Without this variable ntaReqRef, my ajax works nicely but once I add this variable, it just keeps going to the error function of ajax. This is my server side code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
var insertDocument = function(db, req, callback) { 
db.collection('documents').insertOne({
//'_id': Object.keys(obj).length,
    'samID': req.body.samId,
    'itemDescription': req.body.itemDescrip,
    'issuedQTY': req.body.issueQty,
    'openingQTY':req.body.openQty,
    'closingQTY':req.body.closeQty,
    'corruptedQTY':req.body.corrupQty,
    'Remarks':req.body.remarks,
    'ntaSamRequestRef': req.body.ntaReqRef
    //'Created Date': "<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>"
 }, function(err, results) {

    if(err) return callback(err);
    console.log("Inserted a document into the documents collection.");
    console.log(results);
    var cursor = db.collection('documents').find({
        //'_id': Object.keys(obj).length,
        'samID': req.body.samId,
        'itemDescription': req.body.itemDescrip,
        'issuedQTY': req.body.issueQty,
        'openingQTY':req.body.openQty,
        'closingQTY':req.body.closeQty,
        'corruptedQTY':req.body.corrupQty,
        'Remarks':req.body.remarks,
        'ntaSamRequestRef': req.body.ntaReqRef
        //'Created Date': "<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>"
    }).toArray(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        } else{
        console.log('Successfully queried');
        console.log(doc);
        return callback(null, JSON.stringify(doc));
        }
    });
  });
};
module.exports = {
postCollection : function(req,res){
    var samId = req.body.samId;
    var itemDescrip = req.body.itemDescrip;
    var issueQty = req.body.issueQty;
    //var indexNo = Object.keys(obj).length;
    var openQty = req.body.openQty;
    var closeQty = req.body.closeQty;
    var corrupQty = req.body.corrupQty;
    var remarks = req.body.remarks;
    var ntaReqRef = req.body.ntaReqRef;
    //var createdDate =  "<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>"
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        //assert.equal(null, err);
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            res.end();
        }
        insertDocument(db, req, function(err,doc) {
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            else{
                setTimeout(function(){
                    res.send(doc);
                    res.end();
                },2000);
            }
            db.close();
        });
    });
 }
 }
```

I have tested my api on postman and it works with a response like this `[{"_id":"5959e2448dd75c0908cad3ac","samID":"10","itemDescription":"10","issuedQTY":"1","openingQTY":"1","closingQTY":"1","corruptedQTY":"1","Remarks":"1","ntaSamRequestRef":"11-12"}]`

As for my html code,

```
<div id="insert">  
     <h1>Add a New Record</h1>
      <form class="wrapper-input" method="POST" onsubmit="create()" >
      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          SAM ID<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="samId" id="samIda" name= "samId" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Item Description<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="itemDescrip" id="itemDescrip" name= "itemDescrip" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Issued QTY<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="issuedQty" id="issuedQty" name= "issuedQty" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Opening QTY<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="openingQty" id="openingQty" name= "openingQty" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Closing QTY<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="closingQty" id="closingQty" name= "closingQty" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Corrupted QTY<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="corruptedQty" id="corruptedQty" name= "corruptedQty" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Remarks<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="Remarks" id="Remarks" name= "Remarks" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          NTA SAM Ref Number<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
    <input type="text" id="ntaReqRef" name= "NtaReqRef" oninput="hyphen()" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>
       <input class="button" type="submit" id="inserta" value="Create" />
      </form>
      <div id= "Iresult"></div>
      </div>
```

This is my js code connected to html.

```
function hyphen(){
$('#ntaReqRef').keyup(function() {
    var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
    if (foo.length > 0) {
        foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join("-");
    }
    $(this).val(foo);
});
}

function create(){
var samId = $('#samIda').val();
var itemDescrip = $('#itemDescrip').val();
var issueQty =$('#issuedQty').val();
var openQty = $('#openingQty').val();
var closeQty = $('#closingQty').val();
var corrupQty = $('#corruptedQty').val();
var remarks = $('#Remarks').val();
var ntaReqRef = $('#ntaReqRef').val();
var postData = { "samId": samId,  "itemDescrip": itemDescrip, "issueQty" : issueQty,
                "openQty" : openQty, "closeQty" :closeQty, 
                "corrupQty": corrupQty, "remarks": remarks, "ntaReqRef": ntaReqRef };
    var postJSON = JSON.stringify(postData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/api/insertRecord", // server url
        type: "POST", //POST or GET
        contentType: "application/json", // data to send in ajax format or querystring format
        data: postJSON,
        dataType : "JSON", //dataType is you telling jQuery what kind of response to expect
        success: function(response) {
            alert('success');
             $("#Iresult").html("A record has been created. :D");
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert('error');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });


}
```

This was the error when I put a `console.log(response)` in the error function

*Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}*

So I don't exactly have a clue what is wrong. My cors works on and I doubt it my dataType is wrong since I do `JSON.stringify(doc)` which is then sent to the response `res.send(doc)`. As for parsing error, I don't think that my response have parsing errors since I stringify already. I am using node.js for my server-side code that is connected to mongodb. Any help is appreciated! Hopefully there is someone who can detect the problem with my ajax call. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I need `event.preventDefault()` in my ajax call to make it a success event which is rather weird so if anyone has an explanation for that feel free to answer I will accept that answer.